# How can I get connected to a network printer in a different subnet with Windows 7 Professional?

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, subnet, network-printer

So we have a mixed node set on our network with Win XP Pro, Win 7 Pro, Ubuntu 11.04, Win 2k3 Server Std, etc all within in an **Active Directory Environment**.  We also have network printers that are shared out via servers at each site where ultimately each site has a different subnet (**Site 1:**  **132.98.1.x/24**, **Site 2: 132.98.2.x/24**, etc with a **subnet mask if 255.255.255.0**). However, the few Win 7 Pro machines we have error out when trying to connect. With our Win XP machines in site 1, there are no issues connecting to the printers at site 2.  **The error reads exactly as follows:**

**"Windows couldn't connect to the printer. Check the printer name and try again.  If this is a network printer, make sure the printer is turned on, and what the printer address is correct."**

Other Important Details

- Windows firewall is turned off
- The network location is set to Work for Win 7 machines
- Other network related programs (WinVNC, FTP, Etc) do work between sites
- Back-door access to remote directories does not work (ex:  \\132.98.2.100\C$) in differeing subnets
- Symantec Endpoint Protection 11 is installed on ALL machines
- Connection to network printers does work within the same subnet.
- Subnets connected via Cisco routers on 192.168.1.0/24
- Routers are unrestricted between sites

My hunch is that theres an authentication issue, but not sure where to start.  **How can I get connected to a network printer in a different subnet with Windows 7 Professional?**

Comment: nitpick: classful networking doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @MarkM Wow, thats a profound statement to me.  When did I miss this memo?

Comment: [1993](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing)

Comment: Damn academia with all of its outdated professors.  Thanks for the enlightenment!  nitpicks never hurt if open for correction ;)

Comment: The problem as I see it is still that a device on 132.98.1.0/24 cannot communicate with a device on 132.98.2.0/24, so you need something in the middle to handle the routing of traffic.  Is there a device to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes, there are Cisco routers that sit between the sites that are on the same network: 192.168.1.x

Still, would this make a difference to a problem only experienced on Windows 7?

Comment: What happens when you run: net view \\printsvr from the Win 7.  Do you see the printer being advertised?

Comment: The console pauses for a good 20 seconds and comes back with "System error 53 has occured. The network path was not found."  Going to see if I can find anyting out with the error 53.

Comment: Do something more simple, can you ping one of the printers from the Windows 7 machine?

Comment: I get ping replies on both the server and printer on site 2 from site 1 on Win 7.

Comment: Did you ping IP or name? When you nslookup on the name, are you getting the correct IP back from the DNS server you expected?

Comment: Name resolution works with ping.  Nslookup returns correct IP address for DNS.

Comment: How are you trying to add the printer? Are you adding it as a Local Printer and creating a new TCP/IP port? Are you using the hostname or IP address?

Comment: Tried both, nata.  I now have reason to beleive, however, that port 445 (domain services?) has something to do with situation and am questioning whether if the routers are truly unrestriced.  We sub out or ntework administration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the person that setup the machines used a our bidirectional firewall as the default gateway and almost definately has port 445 blocked.  This would explain why just those machines were unable to communicate domain related objects, but could still ping back and forth.  Thank you everbody for your input.

Comment: That would do it. The comments on your question should help guide your troubleshooting in the future.